# Titanium on Rails (JavaScript ActiveRecord REST Client)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, activerecord, titanium, appcelerator

I am a beginner with Appcelerator Titanium. It seems very cool. However - dealing with REST services could be easier. Then I found some JavaScript libraries for doing this Rails style database communication... "ActiveRecord". Especially https://github.com/thoughtbot/jester seems kinda cool, since it is ActiveRecord via a Rails app through JSON/XML.

I like the simplicity. You don't have to setup the models... it just gets the properties from the XML/JSON it fetches. It is really, really easy.

However, Jester does not work for Titanium. So my question is... is there a service like Jester for Titanium?

- I actually found a version of Jester made for Titanium... but I didn't manage to get it work: https://github.com/hornairs/jester

I know there are some ActiveRecord services made for Titanium... like Joli.js (github.com/xavierlacot/joli.js)... but it speaks directly to a database. What I am seeking, is such a library - just communicating via a rest api.

Comment: I haven’t tried it with Titanium yet, but you might want to have a look at Backbone.js (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/). It’s model/collection layer should do what you need and is somewhat similar to Jester.

Comment: I am running a standard Rails 3 app with a Titanium mobile client. I'm not clear on what benefits you are looking for. I formulate JSON on the phone, send a request and Rails handles everything.